# Change the Default into a new Picture

Tags: javascript, jquery

Goal:
To have a top.png as a default instead of the current default.

Problem
I have tried changing the javascript from ScrollImg: false into "scrollImg: { active: true, type: 'background', src: 'img/top.png' }" but it doesn't work.

The demo is located in this link.

https://markgoodyear.com/2013/01/scrollup-jquery-plugin/

Do you know how to do it?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: i don't really get, what you mean... could you provide some sample html and js?

Comment: You need to download the sourcecode to understand better.

Comment: you could put your code on http://jsfiddle.net, it's better for reading.

Comment: This context, it doesnt work to add the code in the jsfidde due to many files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use right css file, in this case - image.css.

So, include it in your file:

```
<link id="scrollUpTheme" rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/image.css">
 <script src="../dist/lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../dist/jquery.scrollUp.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(function(){
  $.scrollUp({scrollText: false});
});
 </script>
```

As you can see, even with minimal setup - it will work. I've just removed scrollText, which overlaps top.png. If your paths are ok (i've used github files/folder structure) - then image should be visible.

P.S. image.css content:

```
#scrollUp {
    background-image: url("../../img/top.png");
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 38px;    /* Width of image */
    height: 38px;   /* Height of image */
}
```

So, it should be pretty customizable, without changing of plugin code it self... 
Plugin creates #scrollUp element - and you can apply your custom image/css, too, if you need it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your instruction. The latest changes that I meed was to change the javascript from ScrollImg: false into "scrollImg: { active: true, type: 'background', src: 'img/top.png' }" inside of jquery.scrollUp.js and then I changed the code   <link id="scrollUpTheme" rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/tab.css"> into        <link id="scrollUpTheme" rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/image.css"> in index.html. Did you do the same approach and did you retrieve the result?

Comment: I didn't and i wouldn't change plugin code - you can set default options, when you call plugin:  $.scrollUp({scrollText: false, your other options here...}); Use CSS to style #scrollUp element to fit your needs...  P.S. - desired result is achieved with using unchanged plugin code, unchanged css...

Comment: is it possible that you can provide the whole source cide in index.html?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sL3c1v12/6/  (placed plugin code in head - your custom image appears) Again, you just should remove scrollText, and everything works fine, no need for additional options).

Comment: So: order of calls -> your background image css, jquery, plugin, plugin initialization code on your page:  <script>
 $(function(){
  $.scrollUp({scrollText: false});
});
 </script>, make sure paths are ok -> you are good to go...

Comment: Thank you for your help!